# Mapping columns from JSON in an Azure SQL Data Flow task

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am attempting a simple SELECT action on a Source JSON dataset in an Azure Data Factory data flow, but I am getting an error message that none of the columns from my source are valid. I use the exact configuration as the video, except instead of a CSV file, I use a JSON file.

In the video, at 1:12, you can see that after configuring the source dataset, the source projection shows all of the columns from the source schema.  Below is a screen shot from the tutorial video:
image.png
[image]

And below is a screen shot from my attempt:
(I blurred the column names because they match column names from a vendor app)
[image]

Note in my projection, I am unable to modify the data types or the format.  I'm not sure why not, but I don't need to modify either so I moved on.   I did try with a CSV and I was able to modify the data types.  I'm assuming this is a JSON thing, but I'm noting here just in case there is some configuration that I should take a look at.

At 6:48 in the video, you'll see the user add a select task, exactly as I have done.  Below is a screen shot of the select task in the tutorial immediately following adding the task:
[image]

Notice the source columns all appear.  Below is a screen shot of my select task:
[image]

I'm curious why the column names are missing?  If I type them in manually, I get an error: "Column not found"

For reference, below are screen shots of my Data Source setup.  I'm using a Data Lake Storage Gen2 Linked Service connected via Managed Identity and the AutoResolvingIntegrationRuntime.
[image]
[image]
Note that I tried to do this with a CSV as well.  I was able to edit the datatype and format on a CSV, but I get the same column not found error on the next step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing this in a different browser or clear your browser cache.  It may just be a formatting thing in the auto-generated JSON.  This has happened to me before.

Comment: FYI, you cannot modify data types in source projection with JSON formats.

However, whatever shows up in your Source projection should also be available as metadata in your subsequent transformations.

Click on the Select transformation and click Inspect. Let us know what columns are showing there.

Also, if you are able to, paste a copy of the data flow script behind from the UI.

Comment: I'm embarrassed that the browser clear worked.  I didn't think not being able to change data type was a big deal but thought it was worth mentioning.  Thank you to both!