# deleting rows in azure data flow

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-data-factory

I am trying to clean a data frame In azure data flow using alter row operation. I  have created a blob link service with CSV file (5 columns). Then created a data flow as follows: Please refer to the image attached.

enter image description here 
[image]

[image]

As you can see in the third image, alterrow still contains zero columns, not picking up columns from the source file. Can anyone tell me why this is happening?

[image]

Comment: That seems weird. Can you delete your AlterRow1 and add a new AlterRow? Then click on Inspect on the Alter Row transformation, make sure you can now see your columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Mark Kromer refers,you can delete your AlterRow1 and add a new AlterRow.If it doesn't work,try doing this in a different browser or clear your browser cache.It looks the same as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61876786/mapping-columns-from-json-in-an-azure-sql-data-flow-task).